# How to Knit a Rmd file with R code to generate a word document

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I have created an Rmd file and I know that if I go to the tools bars and select "knit to word" it will generate a word document form me.

My question is how can I do this with R code without having to actually clicking on the "knit to word" option on the top tool bar?

I have this code but the word document it creates does not work

```
library(knitr)
knit("AutomationPricingReport.Rmd", "AutomationPricingReport.docx")
```

Comment: You can use `rmarkdown::render("AutomationPricingReport.Rmd", output_file = "AutomationPricingReport.docx")`

Comment: Thanks, that work perfect! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
rmarkdown::render("AutomationPricingReport.Rmd", 
                  output_file = "AutomationPricingReport.docx"
                 )
```

Comment: For me only the following code worked `rmarkdown::render("Document.Rmd", word_document())`

Answer (score 5):

You can specify `output: word_document` in the YAML metadata at the top of the document.