# Automating Knitting a Word doc and emailing it with R

Tags: r

I have a .rmd file that pulls daily data and analyzes it. Currently, I am running the script daily, knitting it, and emailing the Word doc to those who need to see it.

Is there a way to automate this process? Is there coding I can write in R that will send them knitted doc to the people who need to see it?

Comment: There are tutorials which walk through how to do this with a chron job on your computer, eg using the `taskscheduleR` package.

Comment: For one of my programs, I have rmarkdown create a file, and then use the package sendmailR to attach and send it to the list of people I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is... at least definitely if you are sending from a gmail account.

I use `library(emayili)` to send emails from my code often.

I believe something like this might work for you:

```
  recipients <- c("email address 1", "email address 2")
  
  email <- envelope() %>%
    from("senders email account") %>%
    to(recipients) %>%
    subject("subject") %>%
    text("body") %>% attachment("file name", path = "file path as saved onto your pc")
  
  smtp <- server(host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                 port = 465,
                 username = "your email username",
                 password = "your email password")
  
  smtp(email, verbose = TRUE)
```

I did notice that to actually attach the file, you need to have a body to the email as well. Not just the attachment.

That's the email part.

For the knitting part, try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52486600/16053848)

```
rmarkdown::render("AutomationPricingReport.Rmd", 
                  output_file = "AutomationPricingReport.docx"
                 )
```

As Jon Spring pointed out in the comments, `library(taskscheduleR)` is probably your best bet to automate running the script.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I now have Windows automatically running the file at a specified time also. Thanks so much.

Comment: That's great! I'm glad I could help you out. Please consider marking the answer as accepted :)